# Data correlation and concurrent users with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

This is Naresh. Seems this blog is really helpful for the beginners and all.

I have chosen Jmeter for Perf. testing web-based application and it is build with the environment - Microsoft dot net(Asp.net 3.5 with C#). Would Jmeter helps me?

I have done some sample recordings, for e.g login and search.

Scenario1 - Login

Here I have recorded for login and then parameterized with CSV config file.

And executed later.

As I do not much hand on exp, do I need to add anything to the above config to run it perfectly. For e.g. adding HTTP cookie manager or ?????

How to run the concurrent users?

Scenario 2:

Here, I have logged in - login.aspx is recorded
given a search - search.aspx is recorded
results will be displayed right below the search in a tabular format - (same)search.aspx is recorded

I want to run this for 100 simultaneous search(s). I understood how to pass the CSV file.

I am sure there is some thing needed to be done for executing this scenario.

Do I have need to do Data correlation, if yes? how to do this?

Do I need to add HTTP cookie manager or HTTP cache manager......

Please help guys, would be grateful :)

Naresh

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must add the HTTP Cookie manager and HTTP cache manager